# Swift 5. Кнопка Done на keypad’e

Tags: ios, swift, login

На экране авторизации, при заполнении полей Логина кнопка Return(Next) переключает фокус между полями. После ввода пароля в поле Password кнопка Done на keypad’e должна дублировать логику работы кнопки Log In. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас `UITextField`, назначьте делегат `UITextFieldDelegate` и в методе [`textFieldShouldReturn(textField:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619603-textfieldshouldreturn) выполняйте что нужно:

```swift
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    performLoginAction()
    return true
}
```